# Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

hello friends i am use cocos2d and viewcontroller in my project. first load my apps at that time first cocos2d scene load successfully . after i am push that scene to viewcontroller its also working fine.but after i push again to scene at that time i have error as Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported.i try more but not get anything solution.

my code as below

director_ that push app to scene

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 navController_ = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];

}
```

After i push scene to viewconreoller as below

```
-(void)SceneToController
{
         ViewController *yourViewController = [[ViewController  alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

        [[CCDirector sharedDirector].navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
}
```

i successfully come to viewcontroller

after i push to viewController to scene as below code

```
-(void)ViewToScene
{

     AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    [director_ pushScene:[NewLayer scene]];

    [[app navController] pushViewController:director_ animated:YES];
}
```

But it got error as Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported. plese help me about it

Comment: Why are you trying to push to that controller, rather than popping yourViewController to get back to the one you already have as the root view controller?

Comment: You dont need to push viewcontroller if you want to go back to that view controller. Use popViewControllerAnimated or popToRootViewControllerAnimated instead

Comment: friends i have hellowordlayer after push deedviewcontroller and afetr i push newLayer. not same HellowordLayer